# How to merge same value cells in Excel and create a new list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of candidates with different scores for 2 different papers. I have to merge the students and their marks.

The difficult/tricky part is that list of candidates in both rows are different. Some are same.

See this original list for example:
[image]

I have to merge the cells with same Names and create a new list like the one mentioned below:
[image]

How do I go about doing this? I hope the screenshots are helpful.

Comment: What? I'm sorry. I don't get you. If you are asking if Name1, Name2... should be NameA, NameB, NameC.. that format works too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in the result column I, row 2, and copy down.

```
=VLOOKUP($G2,Names2, 2,FALSE)
```

The named range `Names2` is the range defined as C1:D9 in your example. It could be on another sheet if you define the name with a Workbook scope. The formula throws a #N/A error if a matching name isn't found. I think this is beneficial (the error display could be suppressed).

Comment: I'm sorry but that nameX is actually just a sample. Names are in the format Elaine Byrne, Donald Trump, Hillary Clinton, etc and not Name1, Name2. I'm sorry. I didn't explain properly. Thank You though.

Comment: I understood that. The above formula will do the job as long as the names in List1 and List2 are identical. Hillary Clinton in one list and Hillary R Clinton in the other will not be matched. You sound like you didn't get the expected result and, if so, I would like to know your experience when you tried to apply the formula I suggested.